# XML order using FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I wrote an XML query that creates an order in the sligthly different format that I would like it to:

```
select
    'sample' "@ponumber",
    'xxxxxx' "@cust",
    'yyyyyy' "@shipto",
    '999999'  "line/material",
    '20'      "line/qty",
    '777777'  "line/material",
    '20'      "line/qty"
for 
    xml path('root')
```

I get the following output:

```
<root ponumber="sample" cust="xxxxxx" shipto="yyyyyy">
  <line>
    <material>999999</material>
    <qty>20</qty>
     <material>777777</material>
    <qty>20</qty>
  </line>
</root>
```

The desired output is this:

```
<root ponumber="sample" cust="xxxxxx" shipto="yyyyyy">
  <line>
    <material>999999</material>
    <qty>20</qty>
  </line>
  <line>
    <material>777777</material>
    <qty>20</qty>
  </line>
</root>
```

What do I need to modify in my query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would give you the desired output. The way it works is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29234102/243373) on Stack Overflow.

```
select
    'sample' "@ponumber",
    'xxxxxx' "@cust",
    'yyyyyy' "@shipto",
    '999999'  "line/material",
    '20'      "line/qty",
    '',
    '777777'  "line/material",
    '20'      "line/qty"
for 
    xml path('root')
```

Produces

```
<root ponumber="sample" cust="xxxxxx" shipto="yyyyyy">
  <line>
    <material>999999</material>
    <qty>20</qty>
  </line>
  <line>
    <material>777777</material>
    <qty>20</qty>
  </line>
</root>
```

Comment: That's weird.. at least to me.. +1

Comment: Plus1 -  shockingly simple!  I've twisted myself into knots to create the proper nesting.

Comment: Yeah it's crazy how that works. I used to do it with subqueries until I saw that trick recently. Shockingly simple indeed, but also a bit counter intuitive IMO.

Comment: Great transfer! :-)